# Powershell, Loop, Array valuable, why Powershell can not recognize valuable in Loops

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell

I am very new to programming, I have a code like this.

```
$azuresubscription = get-azuresubscription



for($K = 0; $K -le $azuresubscription.Length -1; $K++){

$s= $azuresubscription[$K]|select SubscriptionName

$s 
Write-Host "++++++++++++++++++++";
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $s   

}
```

and echo out is

```
SubscriptionName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----------------
CAT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
++++++++++++++++++++
select-azuresubscription : Must specify a non-null subscription name.
Parameter name: name
At line:12 char:1
+ select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand

Dog                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
++++++++++++++++++++
select-azuresubscription : Must specify a non-null subscription name.
Parameter name: name
At line:12 char:1
+ select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand

 Bird                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
++++++++++++++++++++
select-azuresubscription : Must specify a non-null subscription name.
Parameter name: name
At line:12 char:1
+ select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

so I tried like this

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName "CAT"
```

It works, 
According to the error, it seems Powershell think that $s is null

why Powershell can not recognize $s as CAT, Dog or Bird? How can I change that?

Comment: The main thing to remember about PS is that it's .NET, thus everything is a .NET object. If you want the string, that's where `-expand` comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-Expand` option on the `select`

```
$azuresubscription = get-azuresubscription

for($K = 0; $K -le $azuresubscription.Length -1; $K++) {
    $s = $azuresubscription[$K] | select -Expand SubscriptionName

    Write-Verbose -Verbose "`$s = $s" 
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "++++++++++++++++++++";
    select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $s   
}
```

In the initial form, you're getting the powershell object that contains a subset of properties you selected. With `-ExpandProperty` or `-Expand` for short, you get the actual value of the property named.

A more powershell-y way to do it would also be:

```
get-azuresubscription | 
   ForEach-Object { 
       select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName $_.SubscriptionName   
   }
```

Or possibly even shorter (If Azure commands support the pipeline correctly):

```
get-azuresubscription | select-azuresubscription
```